# How to get rawValue of enum using there sub function?

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum that is defined like below.

```
enum PurchaseTimeType: Int,CaseIterable {
    case ASAP, ThisMonth, NextMonth
    func id() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .ASAP:
            return 1
        case .ThisMonth:
            return 2
        case .NextMonth:
            return 3
        }
    }
    func title() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .ASAP:
            return "ASAP"
        case .ThisMonth:
            return "This Month"
        case .NextMonth:
            return "Next Month"
        }
    }
}
```

I have `id` stored in one variable:

```
var id = 1
```

How can I get the `title()` for that `id`?

Comment: Please don't add arbitrary tags. This is not iOS related, and there is no Objective-C code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a custom init with id like this

```
enum PurchaseTimeType: Int,CaseIterable {
    case ASAP, ThisMonth, NextMonth
    func id() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .ASAP:
            return 1
        case .ThisMonth:
            return 2
        case .NextMonth:
            return 3
        }
    }
    func title() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .ASAP:
            return "ASAP"
        case .ThisMonth:
            return "This Month"
        case .NextMonth:
            return "Next Month"
        }
    }
    init?(id: Int) {
        switch id {
        case 1:
            self = .ASAP
        case 2:
            self = .ThisMonth
        case 3:
            self = .NextMonth
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And you can init a PurchaseTimeType instance with an Int. Then you can get its title as follows

```
let num = 1
if let purchaseTimeType = PurchaseTimeType(id:num) {
    print(purchaseTimeType.title())//ASAP
    print(purchaseTimeType.id())//1
}
```

Comment: Looking for dynamic solution, Assume there is another function that will return description then what should i do?

Comment: @PinkeshGjr If you have another function that returns description, Do you want to get other values from a description string?

Comment: Yes let's assume we have multiple function and want to get title or description based on id so that will not work with init.

Comment: @PinkeshGjr Do you want to get title or description based on id and get title or id based on description ?

Comment: Only title and description based on id, id is primary variable.

Comment: @PinkeshGjr Then you can get     print(purchaseTimeType.description())

Comment: Thank you so much you have save my time :)

Answer (score 1):

You assign your `Int` id to each case, like so:

```
enum PurchaseTimeType: Int, CaseIterable {
    case asap = 1
    case thisMonth = 2
    case nextMonth = 3

    // All above cases can also be written in one line, like so
    // case asap = 1, thisMonth, nextMonth

    var id: Int {
        return self.rawValue
    }

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .asap:
            return "ASAP"
        case .thisMonth:
            return "This Month"
        case .nextMonth:
            return "Next Month"
        }
    }

}
```

**Usage-1**

```
let purchaseTime: PurchaseTimeType = .thisMonth

print(purchaseTime.id, ":", purchaseTime.title)
```

**Usage-2:** Filter by id

```
let id = 1
if let type = PurchaseTimeType.allCases.first(where: { $0.id == id } ) {
    print("Title for \(id) is \(type.title)")
}
```

*Note* I updated the case names from **UPPERCASE** to follow convention, each case should be named **lowerCamelCase** with a lowercase first letter and capital letter for each subsequent words.

Comment: I am using this enum to display in tableView so that will not work if i will manually assign rawValue. 
Looking for dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below

```
class PurchaseTime {

    var id: Int!
    var title: String!
    init(id: Int, title: String) {

        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
}

enum PurchaseTimeType: Int,CaseIterable {
    case ASAP, ThisMonth, NextMonth

    var instance: PurchaseTime {

        switch self {

            case .ASAP:        return PurchaseTime(id: 1, title: "ASAP")
            case .ThisMonth:   return PurchaseTime(id: 2, title: "This Month")
            case .NextMonth:   return PurchaseTime(id: 3, title: "Next Month")
        }
    }
}

PurchaseTimeType.ASAP.instance.id
PurchaseTimeType.ASAP.instance.title


let id = 1
if let type = PurchaseTimeType.allCases.first(where: { $0.instance.id == id } ) {
    print(type.instance.title)
}
```

I hope its work for you

Comment: How will i get title of any id?